# Can you find Big Foot in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Can you find Big Foot in GTA V? If yes, what mission, which character, and where do I have to be looking to see Big Foot?

Comment: C'mon ... spoiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two missions that have bigfoot in it:

- `Predator`
- `The Last One`

The first mission, `Predator`, is the mission where you snipe the O'Neil brothers in the woods.

This video shows bigfoot's location in the Predator mission (Bigfoot section at 0:44):

The second mission, `The Last One`, is a Franklin "Strangers and Freaks" mission.

If you want more info, go to the link below (***WARNING: SPOILERS IN THE LINK***):

> [The Last One *(CONTAINS SPOILERS)*](http://gta.wikia.com/The_Last_One)